# how to alter primary key in generic statement?

Tags: mysql

how to alter primary key in  generic statement?

What I have done
step1:- select * from temp_abc;

```
INSERT INTO temp_abc
        (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'xts_broker_b1' 
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_basket_data' 
            AND COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI');
```

explaination :- first create temporary table (select * from temp_abc;)
read all primary keys and insert into temp table

step2 :-

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pri_key SEPARATOR ',') INTO @disPrikey 
FROM tbl_abc;
```

`@disPrikey` is local  varible in that stored all primary key,whatever key are present in temp table

explaination:-The GROUP_CONCAT() function in MySQL is used to concatenate data from multiple rows into one field

step3:-

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(",", @disPrikey,"SystemBrokerID") INTO @PKey ;
```

explaination:- The CONCAT_WS() function adds two or more expressions together with a separator.

`SystemBrokerID` is my key that I need to alter

step4:-

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_basket_data DROP primary key, ADD PRIMARY KEY (PKey);
```

but `@Pkey` is local varible but i need pass here column name , so not getting how add here